# How to mask present unemployment when asking for recommendation

Tags: recommendation-letter

I voluntarily quit my job 6 months ago. I need to get a letter of recommendation from a professor I know for grad school, and I want to include my resume in the email I send this professor.

What is the best way to mask or downplay the fact that I've been (voluntarily) unemployed for 6 months?

Is it too bad if I remove employment history altogether from my resume?

Comment: Whatever you do, always be honest.

Comment: Why do you think this is necessary?

Comment: What have you been doing? You said it was voluntary, have you been raising a child, taking classes? You can say what you were doing even if it wasn't working for the man.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your professor is going to change the letter of recommendation based on your employment history. In fact, I'm pretty sure most professors would not be looking over that part of your resume very closely because it's not relevant to the letter they need to write.

Don't leave out your employment history though, that looks really weird.

Comment: I think some professors, at least, would try harder to help you if they knew you'd been out of work. Don't assume the opposite in any case unless you know more.